# Can't remove Listbox items from listbox

Tags: silverlight

I have a listbox in a Silverlight application.
The listbox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="lbHazards" Margin="5"
         MinHeight="75" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HazListByTaskIDCollection}"
         DisplayMemberPath="sHaz_Name"
         IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" />
```

In the view model I have

```vb
Private _HazListByTaskIDCollection As ObservableCollection(Of vw_HazList_By_TaskID)

Public Property HazListByTaskIDCollection() As ObservableCollection(Of vw_HazList_By_TaskID)
    Get
        Return _HazListByTaskIDCollection
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of vw_HazList_By_TaskID))
        _HazListByTaskIDCollection = value
        'Used to notify CommonBase class that a property change has occured
        RaisePropertyChanged("HazListByTaskIDCollection")
    End Set
End Property
```

Then I have a sub in the viewmodel:

```vb
Public Sub FillHazList(ByVal iHazID As Integer, ByVal sHaz_Name As String)
    Try

        Dim yy = New vw_HazList_By_TaskID

        yy.iHazID = iHazID
        yy.sHaz_Name = sHaz_Name

        HazListByTaskIDCollection.Add(yy)


    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayError("Error Happened", ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

And that works perfectly when this Sub is called the item is added to the listbox.
But I also need to be able to remove the items from the listbox
So I thought it would be easy enough so I created another sub

```vb
Public Sub RemoveHazListItem(ByVal iHazID As Integer, ByVal sHaz_Name As String)
    Try
        Dim yyy = New vw_HazList_By_TaskID

        yyy.iHazID = iHazID
        yyy.sHaz_Name = sHaz_Name
        HazListByTaskIDCollection.Remove(yyy)

        HazListByTaskIDCollection.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayError("Error Happened", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This runs with no errors but it does NOT remove the item from the listbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RemoveHazListItem` method appears to be creating a new `vw_HazList_By_TaskID` object, putting a couple of values in it, and attempting to remove this newly-created object from your collection.  It seems you're not getting the behaviour you are expecting because you're attempting to remove from a collection an item that was never added to it.

As far as I can see, there are two solutions to your problem:

1. Override `Equals` in your `vw_HazList_By_TaskID` class.  Doing this should allow new objects to be considered equal to existing objects in the collection, and hence you should be able to remove objects from the collection by passing to `Remove` an object that is equal to the one you want to remove.
2. Look through the collection for a `vw_HazList_By_TaskID` object with matching `iHazID` and `sHaz_Name` properties, and remove that object from the collection instead.

Incidentally, the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.95).aspx) method of the `ObservableCollection(Of T)` class returns a `Boolean` value indicating whether it was able to remove a value from the list.  In the event of the item to remove not being found, it returns `False` as opposed to throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
HazListByTaskIDCollection.RemoveAt(HazListByTaskIDCollection.IndexOf(yyy));
```